# Remove duplicates, keeping most frequent row

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to deduplicate my data, keeping the row that has the most frequent appearances. If there is a tie in rows, I don't care which gets returned—the first in alphabetical or numeric order is fine. I would like to do this by group of `id` and `var`.

MRE:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = rep("a", 8),
  var = c(rep("b", 4), rep("c", 4)),
  val = c("d", "d", "d", "e", "f", "f", "g", "g")
)

> df
  id var val
1  a   b   d
2  a   b   d
3  a   b   d
4  a   b   e
5  a   c   f
6  a   c   f
7  a   c   g
8  a   c   g
```

Should be:

```
  id var val
1  a   b   d
2  a   c   f
```

I'm working with large datasets and `tidyverse` pipe chains, so a `dplyr` solution would be preferable.

Comment: Isn't a-b-d the most frequent row? Why is a-c-f being returned also?

Comment: I’m wanting to group it by id and var. I was going to take the solution provided here and put it downstream of a group by. Walking home now but will update question when I get there if no one else has by then.

Comment: Oh, I see. I suppose the solution provided by @Psidom should do the trick then.

Comment: Yes, they got what I wanted.

Comment: I think the 2nd row can either be `a   c   f` or `a   c   g`. Is that correct?

Comment: @MKR correct—I have no preference outside of taking the most frequent one. One could probably make a compelling case that it should be randomly decided between `a c f` and `a c g`

Comment: Then my solution will work without further change.

Comment: @MKR correct, I gave it a +1. Trying to see which is quickest for my purposes now

Comment: That will be really informative exercise. Let's wait for result. Thanks.

Comment: @MKR so let's say there's a tie and when that happens we want to take a random row. Instead of `slice(1)`, we could do `slice(sample(1:n(), 1)`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `table` and `which.max` to extract the `mode`:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(id, var) %>% 
    summarise(val = {t <- table(val); names(t)[which.max(t)] })

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   id [?]
#  id    var   val  
#  <fct> <fct> <chr>
#1 a     b     d    
#2 a     c     f
```

---

Another way to do this in base R: Create a three way contingency table directly, and then find the max column along the third axis:

```
apply(table(df), c(1, 2), function(v) names(v)[which.max(v)])

#   var
#id  b   c  
#  a "d" "f"
```

Convert this to a data frame:

```
as.data.frame.table(
    apply(table(df), c(1, 2), function(v) names(v)[which.max(v)])
)

#  id var Freq
#1  a   b    d
#2  a   c    f
```

Comment: Accepted for best combination of being (a) concise and readable and (b) the quickest when doing `microbenchmark` on my present use-case

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this is any faster, but another option is

```
df %>% 
    group_by(id, var) %>% 
    filter(row_number() == rle(as.character(val))$lengths %>% 
                                {sum(.[1:which.max(.)])})
```

Answer (score 2):

Using *dplyr*:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(id, var, val) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  group_by(id, var) %>% 
  arrange(-n) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-n)

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   id    var   val  
#   <fct> <fct> <fct>
# 1 a     b     d    
# 2 a     c     f
```

Answer (score 2):

One option could be using `table` and `max` as:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id, var) %>%
  filter(table(val) == max(table(val))) %>%
  slice(1)
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
# # Groups: id, var [2]
# id     var    val   
# <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>
# 1 a      b      d     
# 2 a      c      g
```

**NOTE:** `a c g` is case of tie. Per OP any record can be returned in case of tie.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my try:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id,var,val) %>%
  mutate(n=n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(n)) %>%
  group_by(id,var) %>%
  filter(row_number()==1) %>%
  select(-n)
```

`

Comment: You are missing "most frequent" bit. If the 4th row was 1st row, then your output would give `a b e`

Comment: @zx8754 yes, misunderstood the question and updated the version. this should work.

Answer (score 1):

A dplyr solution using count:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  count(id,var,val,sort = T) %>%
  group_by(id,var) %>%
  summarize_at("val",head,1)

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#       id    var    val
#   <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>
# 1      a      b      d
# 2      a      c      f
```

or maybe more idiomatic but longer:

```
df %>%
  count(id,var,val,sort = T) %>%
  group_by(id,var) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  ungroup
```

Or with `tally` for same output with slightly different syntax:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id,var,val) %>%
  tally(sort = T) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  ungroup
```

and a base solution :

```
df2 <- aggregate(x ~ .,cbind(df,x=1),sum)
aggregate(val ~ id+var, df2[order(-df2$x),],head,1)
#   id var val
# 1  a   b   d
# 2  a   c   f
```